# How to prove $\cosh$ is injective in range $[0,\infty]$

Tags: exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

Prove that the function  $\cosh: [0, \infty[  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is injective

I have tried to prove $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1=x_2$

I can not figure out how to prove $\frac{e^{x_1} + e^{-x_1}}2 = \frac{e^{x_2} + e^{-x_2}}2 \implies x_1=x_2 \forall x_1,x_2 \in [0, \infty[ $

Comment: The function $e^x$ is strictly monotonic, then it is also $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $x = e^{x_1}, y = e^{x_2} \implies x+\dfrac{1}{x} = y + \dfrac{1}{y} \implies \dfrac{(x-y)(xy-1)}{xy} = 0 \implies x - y = 0$ or $xy = 1$ since $x, y \ge 1$. If $x - y = 0 \implies x = y \implies x_1 = x_2$. If $xy = 1 \implies x = y = 1 \implies x_1 = x_2 = 0 \implies x_1 = x_2$. Thus either case yields a $1-1$ function for $\cosh$

Comment: I'am not allowed to use derivatives